# Access SQL returns today's date which is good but not today's date if it includes a time which is bad

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

The SQL below is supposed to check my "Projects" table for any quote that was completed today, which it does. What it does not do is select any quote completed today if that field also has a time in it (which most do, since it's automatically stamped and management wants to measure turn time in hours and minutes rather than days)

How can I make the following query check date only?

```
SELECT [Customer name], [$ Amount], [Quote Completed], [Store], [Region]
FROM Projects
WHERE ([Quote Completed] = date()-1);
```

The above returns:

```
07/15/2015
```

But not:

```
7/15/2015 12:57:39 PM
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `DateValue([Quote Completed])` to compare just the date part, ignoring the time of day.  However that means the function would have to be evaluated for every row of the *Projects* table and the db engine will not be able to use indexed retrieval.

So with an index on *Quote Completed*, you will be much better off performance-wise to take advantage of the index.  This should give you all rows for yesterday's date regardless of their time of day:

```sql
WHERE [Quote Completed] >= Date()-1 AND [Quote Completed] < Date();
```

I based that suggestion on your SQL sample.  However, you mentioned today's date.  For today's date, use this instead:

```sql
WHERE [Quote Completed] >= Date() AND [Quote Completed] < Date() + 1;
```